# Android Studio Google Map with location

Tags: android, maps

Is it possible to display image in bubble message google map android studio?[image: Display image with some text]

Comment: have you done some research about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.813, 144.962);
private Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(MELBOURNE)
                        .title("Melbourne")
                        .snippet("Population: 4,137,400")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow)));
```

[Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker)